# Condense CSS definitions and HTML DIVs

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm not sure if what I need is self-explanatory so I'll give it a try.

**Please, before proceeding, do note that :**

- I'm using Twitter Bootstrap
- I'm also making extensive use of LESS

---

So, I'm taking the upper navigation as an example. My code is :

```
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style='-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px #888; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px #888; box-shadow: 0 3px 10px #888;'>
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <a class="brand" href="http://www.google.com"><img alt="This is an image" src="<?= base_url('library/img/logo-2.png'); ?>" width="200"/></a>
                        <ul class="nav pull-right">
                            <li class="active"><a href="http://www.google.com"><i class="icon-home icon-lightgray"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.google.com"><i class="icon-th icon-lightgray"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Themes</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.google.com"><i class="icon-wrench icon-lightgray"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Tools</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.google.com"><i class="icon-align-right icon-lightgray"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Blog</a></li>
                            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="http://www.google.com" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000" data-close-others="true"><i class="icon-user icon-lightgray"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Log In<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">An Item 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">An Item 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">An Item 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">An Item 2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**So, I'm thinking - "What do we have here?" :**

- 4 nested DIVs
- Lots of "redundant" classes (I'm not using `navbar` or `navbar-inverse` or `navbar-fixed-top` in *any* other place, and that's the only combination I'm interested in).

**What I'm trying to do**

In a few words, I could imagine the very same thing written something like (or even more) :

```
    <div class="navigation">
                    <a class="brand" href="http://www.google.com"><img alt="This is an image" src="<?= base_url('library/img/logo-2.png'); ?>" width="200"/></a>
                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="http://www.google.com"><i class="icon-home icon-lightgray"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.google.com"><i class="icon-th icon-lightgray"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Themes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.google.com"><i class="icon-wrench icon-lightgray"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Tools</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.google.com"><i class="icon-align-right icon-lightgray"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Blog</a></li>
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="http://www.google.com" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000" data-close-others="true"><i class="icon-user icon-lightgray"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Log In<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">An Item 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">An Item 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">An Item 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">An Item 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
    </div>
```

---

You may not find much use to that, but I still believe it'd make my pages far more readable (in terms of code).

So, how would you go about that?

---

**Disclaimer :** *Please excuse the somewhat weird nature of this question. For someone who still likes writing his own compilers/interpreters/languages for every single bit he doesn't like in the existing ones, I think it's kinda excuseable. :-)*

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: @m90 I think the question is fairly straightforward : How would you go about changing the initial block of HTML (+Bootstrap CSS code) to the exact final block of HTML (with the classes/DIVs reduced/eliminated).

Comment: But didn't you do that already?

Comment: @m90 Nope, I didn't. ( Converting 15 nested Bootstrap classes upon subclasses into one, isn't such a piece of cake - even when using LESS; at least for me that is...). I'm just saying what I want to achieve and looking for suggestions on how to approach the issue...

Comment: @Ejay Well, initially it *was* a real mess. Though I ended up filtering all the definitions I don't need and cleaning the whole thing up. Plus, compressing the final file. So, it's quite... bearable. Finally... lol. :-)

Comment: ah, sorry deleted my comment without realizing you had replied :) I **personally** don't like the mess of CSS that LESS generates, but that's my personal opinion :)

Comment: @Ejay One way I'm being tempted to follow, in order to avoid (at least seeing with my very own eyes) LESS's mess, is to have it compile the code on the fly (using js). I haven't yet tested thoroughly (in terms of speed), but I'll see how it could go... :-)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon if I get you right, **you would like to combine the properties that have been applied to the three divs together under one selector to achieve the same effect?** I don't think there is a simple solution for that, you would need to go with the most obvious solution, which is rewriting you CSS. Even if you mix together the selectors in LESS, if you don't need the separate ones why not just write one instead originally. You can do a lot using pseudo elements, but sometimes the html structure just can not be replaced just by more CSS, especially when you want something more complex.

Comment: @MartinTurjak Yep, Martin, *roughly* that's exactly what I'm trying to do. However, given the way Bootstrap's CSS is structured, this seems almost impossible (if we don't consider re-writing it all from scratch, as you suggest). To be honest, given the complexity of the matter (from a CSS point of view), I've already started thinking about giving up the idea and instead going for the PHP-driven solution (= grouping the seemingly-redundant divs/class, in functions' output). Well, hopefully the code won't strike as *that* ugly...